# Offset management Java patten

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's suppose I have some abstract entity in the system which created each time.

Each of those entities should have two ID - Serial and Sequence.

**UC**

1. Initial state -  A(Serial=1, Sequence=1).
2. Scale out - A(Serial=1, Sequence=1), A(Serial=2, Sequence=2)
3. Scale in - A(Serial=1, Sequence=1)
4. Scale out again -  A(Serial=1, Sequence=1), A(Serial=**4**, Sequence=**3**)

Meaning that sequence id it is kind of offset that stored and previous versions is not used.

Is there any patterns in Java that you would recommend to look, main aim of which is store those values in some generic data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thread safety aside to simplify the solution, start by creating a holder for your sequence.

```java
public record SerialItem(int serial, int sequence) { }
```

Create a holder that maintains a sequence of these items with `scaleOut` and `scaleIn` methods to handle adding and removing of items

```java
public class ScaleHolder {

    private final LinkedList<SerialItem> items = new LinkedList<>();
    private int serial;
    private int sequence;

    public ScaleHolder() {
        scaleOut();
    }

    public List<SerialItem> scaleOut() {
        items.add(new SerialItem(++serial, ++sequence));
        return items();
    }

    public List<SerialItem> scaleIn() {
        if (items.size() > 1) {
            items.removeLast();
            serial++;
        }
        return items();
    }

    public List<SerialItem> items() {
        return List.copyOf(items);
    }

}
```

You can now use this as follows:

```java
var h = new SerialHolder();
h.items();    // [SerialItem[serial=1, sequence=1]]
h.scaleOut(); // [SerialItem[serial=1, sequence=1], SerialItem[serial=2, sequence=2]]
h.scaleIn();  // [SerialItem[serial=1, sequence=1]]
h.scaleOut(); // [SerialItem[serial=1, sequence=1], SerialItem[serial=4, sequence=3]]
```

Comment: Any relevant pattern names for such kind of offset management.

Comment: Not one that's standing out at me. Thinking of patterns to solve a problem is the wrong way to approach software design, you should instead think of applying prior knowledge to solve a problem more naturally where patterns may emerge. Understand patterns, but don't think of them first.